# if-elif-else for a 2-dim numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to update the 27th row of a 2-dimensional numpy array based on the values of the 26th row.
The equivalent code for a one-dimensional python list would look like this.
What is the most efficient way to do this for a 2-dimensional numpy array?

```
if(A[26]==32):
    if A[12]==1:
        if A[11]==1:
            if A[10]==1:
                A[27]=10
            else:
                A[27]=9
        else:
            A[27]=5
    elif A[11]==1:
        A[27]=6
    else:
        A[27]=1
elif A[26]==24:
    A[27]=2
elif A[26]==18:
    A[27]=3
elif A[26]==20:
    A[27]=4
elif A[26]==15:
    A[27]=7
elif A[26]==14:
    A[27]=8
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand how the values should be updated in the 2-dimensional case. Can you please add more info as to what should happen depending on the different values in the 2-dimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the condition into a boolean expression for each value to assign, thus building a mask of columns:

```
mask = (A[26,:] == 32) & (A[12,:]==1) & (A[11,:]==1) & (A[10,:]==1)
A[27,mask] = 10
mask = (A[26,:] == 32) & (A[12,:]==1) & (A[11,:]==1) & (A[10,:]!=1)
A[27,mask] = 9
mask = (A[26,:] == 32) & (A[12,:]==1) & (A[11,:]!=1)
A[27,mask] = 5
mask = (A[26,:] == 32) & (A[12,:]!=1) & (A[11,:]==1)
A[27,mask] = 6
mask = (A[26,:] == 32) & (A[12,:]!=1) & (A[11,:]!=1)
A[27,mask] = 1
mask = (A[26,:] == 24) 
A[27,mask] = 2
mask = (A[26,:] == 18)
A[27,mask] = 3
mask = (A[26,:] == 20)
A[27,mask] = 4  
mask = (A[26,:] == 15)
A[27,mask] = 7    
mask = (A[26,:] == 14)
A[27,mask] = 8
```

*Note that you could use multiple mask variables and avoid repeating or inverting conditions*

```
A26is32 = (A[26,:] == 32)
A12is1  = (A[12,:] == 1)
A11is1  = (A[11,:] == 1)
mask = A26is32 &  A12is1 &  A11is1 & (A[10,:] == 1)
A[27,mask] = 10
mask = A26is32 &  A12is1 &  A11is1 & ~mask 
A[27,mask2] = 9
mask = A26is32 &  A12is1 & ~A11is1
A[27,mask] = 5
mask = A26is32 & ~A12is1 &  A11is1
A[27,mask] = 6
mask = A26is32 & ~A12is1 & ~mask  
A[27,mask] = 1
mask = (A[26,:] == 24) # implicitly & ~A26is32
A[27,mask] = 2
...
```